# Invalid maximum heap size but works when PermSize Given

Tags: java, linux, tomcat8

I have tomcat 8.x running in AWS t2.medium linux instance (4GB RAM)  and I am trying to set tomcat memory  but I get error

setenv.sh

```
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dspring.profiles.active=test"
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m"
```

Error catalina.out

```
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx2048m
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

But If I set the following, it works

setenv.sh

```
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dspring.profiles.active=test"
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -XX:PermSize=64m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
```

Java Version

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_181"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Here it says (if I understand correctly) that maximum heap size cannot exceed a 1/4 of available memory https://plumbr.io/blog/java/should-you-trust-the-default-settings-in-jvm

Comment: But when I set permsize it works. Tomcat loads and shows the allocated memory

Comment: Perm size with 256m max..

Comment: And I read Java 8 does not require you  to set permsize. When I set it. It gives a warning as ignoring the setting. But tomcat  starts.

Comment: Try asking the author of the blog I’ve linked above..